# How to order a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sitefinity

I have a function in sitefinity that returns a list of categories.

```
//return list of categories
    private IList<ICategory> GetCategoryDataSource() {

        var cntManager = new ContentManager(CaseStudyManager.DefaultContentProvider);
        IList allCategories = cntManager.GetCategories();
        List<ICategory> filteredList = new List<ICategory>();
        foreach (ICategory category in allCategories) {

            filteredList.Add(category);

        }
        return filteredList;
    }
```

What I want to know is how to sort this list.

Categories in Sitefinity are as far as i can tell just a string, there are no other fields associated with a category. Therefore I have nothing to sort the categories on, other than appending each category with a number, like:

```
1 - Legal
2 - Financial
3 - Property
```

When these categories are displayed on the website I can then at least trim the parts i need.

Can anyone help with the sorting though?

Thanks
Al

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you can remove your foreach / add statement and replace it with: filteredList.AddRange(allCategories)

Comment: There are no other properties in the ICategory interface?  No Id or CategoryId that you can use? `return filteredList.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryId).ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

Use [IComparer Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you name them like you mentioned, with a prefix, you can do this:

001|xxxxxxx

002|djskdjskd

003|sdkdsajdaks

```
foreach (ICategory category in allCategories) 
{              
    filteredList.Add(category.SubString(4);          
}
```